# Bold vector symbols in heading

Tags: math-mode, sectioning

I want a heading "ExB drift" where the E and B are styled with vector arrows, and where the letters are bold like the rest of the heading. So far I've achieved one or the other, with some font issues. I would prefer to use Linux Libertine typeface, but this is not an absolute.

Miniumum working examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
Fonts: Linux Libertine O, Libertinus Math
\section{$\vec{E}\times\vec{B}$ drift}
$\vec{E}\times\vec{B}$ drift without bold.

\section{$\mathbf{\vec{E}\times\vec{B}}$ drift}
$\mathbf{\vec{E}\times\vec{B}}$ drift with bold.
\end{document}
```

or replace set*font with

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
```

or remove altogether.
Screengrabs of resulting PDFs:

[image: default font (A Computer Modern variant)]

[image: Linux Libertine/Libertinus Math]

[image: Tex Gyre Pagella/Pagella Math]

Is it possible to get the font styled like in Section 2, but with the arrows?

Comment: as @egreg says in his answer, bold carries meaning in math.  what is really important though is that identical notation should be used in both headings and text, so that there can be no confusion by the reader.

Comment: I use non-bold symbols in the text. It's just the heading I want to style. The meaning of E x B is clear from context and I think it looks better if the heading is all boldface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\symbf` command, from `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
Fonts: Linux Libertine O, Libertinus Math
\section{$\symbf{\vec{E}\times\vec{B}}$ drift}
$\vec{E}\times\vec{B}$ drift without bold.

\section{$\symbf{\vec{E}\times\vec{B}}$ drift}
$\symbf{\vec{E}\times\vec{B}}$ drift with bold.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\symbf` removes italicity from the symbols. Then, variables are italic in normal text but upright in headings. That looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid emboldening math in titles: bold math carries semantics.

Anyway, the problem is that Libertinus Math has no bold version, but you can “fake” it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[version=bold]{Libertinus Math}[FakeBold=2]

\xpatchcmd{\bfseries}{\fontseries}{\boldmath\fontseries}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\mdseries}{\fontseries}{\unboldmath\fontseries}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

Fonts: Linux Libertine O, Libertinus Math

\section{$\vec{E}\times\vec{B}$ drift}

$\vec{E}\times\vec{B}$ drift without bold.

\end{document}
```

[image]